# How to modify or increase the tigervncserver display resolution on raspbian stretch?

Tags: pi-3, vnc, raspbian-stretch

I have compiled the tigervnc from source on raspbian stretch and then created a systemd unit `$ nano /etc/systemd/system/x0vncserver.service` as follows,

```
[Unit]
Description=Remote desktop service (VNC)
After=default.target

[Service]
Type=forking
User=pi
ExecStart=/bin/sh -c '/usr/bin/x0vncserver -display :0 -geometry 800x600 -rfbport 5900 -passwordfile /home/pi/.vnc/passwd &'

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

and added these lines to `~/.vnc/config` file

```
geometry=800x600
alwaysshared
dpi=64
```

though it is already available in the repo but the tigervncserver from the repo or my compiled one, all of them is giving me [image: tiny desktop window] whereas in tightvncserver I got a [image: pretty good desktop resolution] I am trying to use the x0vncserver feature of tigervnc for my convenience but it would be great if I can configure it to load the desktop in some higher resolution.

Comment: and when I run `/usr/bin/x0vncserver -display :0 -geometry 800x600+0+0 -rfbport 5900 -passwordfile /home/pi/.vnc/passwd`
the result is,
     Wed Oct 11 23:25:55 2017
     Geometry:    Desktop geometry is set to 656x416+0+0
     Main:        Using evdev codemap

     Main:        XTest extension present - version 2.2
     Main:        Listening on port 5900

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer lies somewhere else. As I am trying to load the 0 desktop and as it by default loads as 656x416, so it is not possible to get any higher resolution than that. To change that I had to edit the `sudo nano /boot/config.txt` and uncomment theses lines

```
framebuffer_width=1280
framebuffer_height=720
```

and then rebooted and this time I got a 1280x720 desktop window using `x0vncserver` by default :)

Answer (score 2):

In order to get VNC connection, you need to install a VNC server in RPi. You can install TightVNC but it creates a separate desktop for every connection. You can go with `x11vnc`, if you want single desktop to be shared among every VNC client and the RPi itself.

**TightVNC Server**

Install TightVNC Server

```
$ sudo apt-get install tightvncserver
```

Next run TightVNC Server which will prompt you for the password and an optional View Only password.

```
$ tightvncserver
```

Once that is done you can start a VNC server from shell prompt using below command:

```
$ vncserver :0 -geometry 1366x768 -depth 24
```

Run at Boot

Create a file in `/etc/init.d` with any name such as `vncserver` with following content:

```
#!/bin/sh
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides: vncboot
# Required-Start: $remote_fs $syslog
# Required-Stop: $remote_fs $syslog
# Default-Start: 2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop: 0 1 6
# Short-Description: Start VNC Server at boot time
# Description: Start VNC Server at boot time.
### END INIT INFO

USER=root
HOME=/root

export USER HOME

case "$1" in
 start)
   echo "Starting VNC Server"
   #Insert your favoured settings for a VNC session
   /usr/bin/vncserver :0 -geometry 1280x800 -depth 16 -pixelformat rgb565
   ;;

 stop)
   echo "Stopping VNC Server"
   /usr/bin/vncserver -kill :0
   ;;

 *)
   echo "Usage: /etc/init.d/vncboot {start|stop}"
   exit 1
   ;;
esac

exit 0
```

Make the file executable using this command

```
$ chmod 755 /etc/init.d/vncboot
```

Enable dependency based boot sequencing

```
$ update-rc.d /etc/init.d/vncboot defaults
```

If enabling dependency based boot sequencing was successful, it says

```
$ update-rc.d: using dependency based boot sequencing
```

But if it says

```
$ update-rc.d: error: unable to read /etc/init.d//etc/init.d/vncboot
```

then try the following command

```
$ update-rc.d vncboot defaults
```

**X11VNC Server**

Install x11vnc Server

```
$ sudo apt-get install x11vnc
```

Store Password

```
$ x11vnc -storepasswd
```

Run the server from shell prompt with password

```
$ x11vnc -usrpw -display :0
```

Run at Boot
Make a directory if not already made

```
$ mkdir ~/.config/autostart
```

Create a file named `x11vnc.desktop` or any with the following content

```
[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Type=Application
Name=X11VNC
Exec=x11vnc -forever -usepw -display :0
StartupNotify=false
Terminal=false
Hidden=false
```

Now reboot your RPi, and you will have a VNC Server ready.

View full document [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0By3r0jR6h8ekYnpPak9kV1NsQkU)

Comment: nice document, you are linking to!! thx